# when I make in android studio comes this error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I make or build project in android studio, these errors comes, please help. I checked all the libraries are connected and apart from that, I noticed that in AndrodManifest.xml error that comes out is not possible to find Activity although correctly specified

```
Android Dex: [BookReader] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Android Dex: [BookReader] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Android Dex: [BookReader] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Android Dex: [BookReader] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Android Dex: [BookReader] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Android Dex: [BookReader] application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Android Dex: [BookReader] system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Android Dex: [BookReader] If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Android Dex: [BookReader] core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Android Dex: [BookReader] repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Android Dex: [BookReader] your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Android Dex: [BookReader] conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Android Dex: [BookReader] you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Android Dex: [BookReader] that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Android Dex: [BookReader] lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Android Dex: [BookReader] 1 error; aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a library that is adding some classes that you shouldn't be adding.

Also based on the prefix for all these output lines, you are building with the internal IntelliJ builder and not the new Gradle-based build-system. You should read online about using the new build system.